# uiscrollview+uiviewcontroller+uiactionsheet

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet

I created an app based on the following tutorial [Multiple Virtual Pages in a Scrollview](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html).
I added a button that when pressed displays a UIActionSheet.  It works great on the first page, but other pages the sheet is not displayed.  I thought this was because the sheet is displayed at (0,0) so I tried initing the sheet with the view's frame.  No luck.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[actionSheet setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Create Event", @"Create Event")];
[actionSheet setDelegate:self];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel")];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Save", @"Save")];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Discard", @"Discard")];
[actionSheet setDestructiveButtonIndex:2];[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];
```

Any one know what's going on here?  And what I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using these functions instead and not setting the frame by yourself

> UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
>                                    initWithTitle:nil
>                                    delegate:self
>                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
>                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
>                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil]

and show the alert with this function

> [popupQuery showInView:self.view];

Good luck.

Comment: I tried this with no luck.  Any other suggestions?  Is there a way for my viewcontroller to 'know' where they are in the scoll view?